# Running regressions iteratively for subsets of pySpark dataframes - partitioning by DF columns or mapPartitions?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, linear-regression

I have sales data by store and product_category for every week in the following format.

```
STORE|PRODUCT_CAT|WK_ENDING|<PREDICTOR_VARIABLES>|TARGET_VARIABLE
S1|P1||2016-01-01|..|....
S1|P1||2016-01-08|..|....
S1|P1||2016-01-15|..|....
S1|P2||2016-01-01|..|....
S1|P2||2016-01-08|..|....
S1|P2||2016-01-15|..|....
S2|P1||2016-01-01|..|....
S2|P1||2016-01-08|..|....
S2|P1||2016-01-15|..|....
S2|P2||2016-01-01|..|....
S2|P2||2016-01-08|..|....
S2|P2||2016-01-15|..|....
...
...
```

As you can see it has multiple records by week for every Store - Product combination.

There could be about 200 different stores and ~50 different product categories i.e. we would have ~200 x ~50 = ~10,000 different Store - product combinations (say). For every such combination we will have data for about 4-5 years i.e. 250 records say.

Requirement is that we run separate regresssion models for each of the store-prod combinations.That means we need to run thousands of regressions but on very small datasets. What is the way to go about this?

Options tried / thought about - 
        1. Usual "FOR" loops - 
        Extracted the unique Store-category combinations and then for each store and for each cat (nested for loop), filtered the data from the above DF and ran the models.
        The process runs for about 10-12 stores and then throws memory errors. Note that the above DF is persisted.
        I have seen for other similar computations, pySpark is not able to handle for loops, if it has to reference the same DF from inside the For loop.

Following is the code snippet -

```
main_df.persist() # This is the master dataframe, containing all the above data that is persisted

from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.regression import LinearRegression
for store in store_lst:
    <some calculations like filtering the master dataframe by store etc.. >
    main_df_by_store = main_df.filter(main_df['store_id']==str(store))
    for cat in cat_lst:
        assembler=VectorAssembler(inputCols=['peer_pos_sales'],outputCol='features')
        traindata=main_df_by_store.filter(main_df_by_store['rbt_category']==str(cat))
        output = assembler.transform(traindata)
        modelfit=output.drop('peer_pos_sales').withColumnRenamed('vacant_pos_sales','label')
        lr = LinearRegression(maxIter=10, regParam=0.3, elasticNetParam=0.8)
        lrModel = lr.fit(modelfit)
        result = lrModel.transform(modelfit)
```

2. Can we create a Window Function, partitioned by Store, Category and then apply a UDF to run the regressions? 
   However, it appears that we can only use built-in functions for Window functions, and not UDF? Is that correct?
   How to handle this? Looping is killing the server.
   This needs to be done in pySpark only.

Comment: Please fix your question formatting. [How to I format my code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)?

Comment: @pault Done. Thanks!